# Extend people search with custom contacts list

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, people-search

I'm trying to extend the default people search (that crawls the user profiles) with contacts I've put in a custom SharePoint list (a kind of external contacts list).

My goal is that when people search for a name, results from the people search (my user profiles) and from the external contacts list appear in the search results.

I know you have to create query rules and/or results sources but this sound confusing for me. Ofcourse i've searched on it on the internet, but a lot of solutions are for SP2010 and since search in 2013 is changed a lot, I'm looking for a clear solution for this.

Anyone who has any information about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use SP2013

The search you do on "people" is basically a standard search with an extra filter parameter that indicates only to return people results. Create a custom content type and make the search return: people results **or** items with your custom contenttype.

The difficulty will be mapping the properties correctly (reuse existig columns!).
Then create a custom display template (start with a copy of an existing one)

Then configure the search page (or create a new one, copy an existing one). 
In the properties of the core results webpart, edit the query to the correct filters and set your custom display template.

This tool might come in handy to test your query results
http://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/